# SOP Boolean expression of state variable and output of a Moore FSM

Tags: boolean-expression, algebra, fsm, truthtable, state-diagram

Disclaimer: I'm studying for an exam, but I don't have to hand in anything.

I have the state transition diagram of the FSM and its states encoding:
[image]
I want to find the Sum-Of-Products Boolean expression of *S<sup>1</sup><sub>0</sub>*   ,    *S<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub>* and ouput *y*.

I've drawn tables for each next state, based on all current states (*S<sub>0</sub>* and *S<sub>1</sub>*) and inputs (*A* and *B*):
[image]
After this, I don't have very clear how to proceed with drawing the output and state table truth / k-map to get the final Boolean expression.

Comment: You have four inputs (s0, s1, A, B) and three outputs (s0', s1', y). This can be written in one truth table with 16 rows, 4 input columns and 3 output columns. For each of the three outputs, you can draw a Karnaugh map and derive a minimized sum-of-products. It might make sense to look at all three maps in parallel when merging cell blocks. This helps to get common subexpressions.

Comment: @AxelKemper thank you for your answer. To retrace this: I’ll have 3 K-maps, based on the 4 inputs, from which I’ll derive the Boolean expressions of my outputs. The only thing I don’t have clear yet, is how to get the truth table of **y**.

Comment: The value of y is bound to the next state: y=0 for s0 and s2, y=1 for s1 and s3.

Comment: @AxelKemper oh, right, that was silly! Now I have everything clear. Thank you for your thorough answers.